# how to insert a value to a foreign key using session without overriding the other sessions in codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

I hope you're doing fine. Can somebody help me with my problem? I have 2 tables. The other one is for customers, it has an auto-increment value for `customer_id`. The other table is for orders, it has an auto-increment also for its `orders_id` and a foreign key from the other table (`customers`).

When I insert a new customer, if it is successful, I want the page to be redirected to the add new order page. In inserting new order, the `customer_id` field in my `orders` table should have the same value as the newly added customer. Adding customer and adding new order is of different function in my controller. I am having an error 1452 when inserting the new order, which means the value inserted for the foreign key `customers_id` in the `orders` table is different with the value in the other table (customers).

Now, I've got this solution using session. My problem is the other session for getting the last id is overriding the session for logging in.

Here's some code snippets from my controller:

```html
Class MyController extends CI_Controller
{ 
 function __construct()
 {
  parent::__construct();
  $this->c_id = 0;
  if($this->session->userdata('logged_in'))
     {
      $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
      $data['username'] = $session_data['username'];
   if($session_data['username'] == 'administrator'){
    $this->load->database('sample');
    $this->load->model('samplemodel_model');
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
   } else {
       redirect('home', 'refresh');
   }

  } else {
   redirect('login', 'refresh');
  }
 }
        public function index() {

  if($this->session->userdata('logged_in'))
     {
            $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
      $data['username'] = $session_data['username'];

      //code for validation here

   $customers = $this->samplemodel_model->get_entries('customers');

      if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
       //Field validation failed.
      } else {
        //Insert $data
                //$data = array('xxxxxx'); 
                //data is something like that
    $this->create($data);
      }
     }
     else
     {
       //If there's no session it will redirect to login page
     }

 }

 //add new orders
 public function addOrders() {
  if($this->session->userdata('last_inserted_id')) //if I use this session, I can get the last inserted ID but the session data for the login will not be retrieved.
     {
      $session_data = $this->session->userdata('last_inserted_id');

   $orders = $this->samplemodel_model->get_entries('orders');

      if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
       //Field validation failed.
      } else {
        //Insert data

       $data = array('customer_id' => $session_data['customer_id'], 
            'order_type' => $this->input->post('order_type'));

    $this->createItem($data);
      }
     }
     else
     {
       //If no session, redirect to login page
       redirect('login', 'refresh');
     }
 }

 //create customer
 public function create($data) {
      //Insert data
  $customers = $this->samplemodel_model->get_entries('customers');

  //$data = array(xxxxx);
        //somethin' like that for data array

  $this->load->samplemodel_model->create('customers', $data);

  //***********************************************************//
  //                get and save last id inserted              //
  //***********************************************************//

   //query the database
     $result = $this->samplemodel_model->get_last_inserted($this->db->insert_id());
     if($result)
     {
      $sess_array = array();
       foreach($result as $row)
       {
          $sess_array = array('customer_id' => $row->customer_id);
          $this->session->set_userdata('last_inserted_id', $sess_array);
       }
       return TRUE;
     }
     else
     {
      echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('error');</script>";
      return false;
     }

     session_start('last_inserted_id');

     //********************************************************//
     //                          end                           //
     //********************************************************// 

  redirect('myController/addOrders', 'refresh');
       
 }
 public function createItem($data) {
  //Insert data
  $orders = $this->samplemodel_model->get_entries('orders');

  $data = array('customer_id' => $session_data['customer_id'],
       'order_type' => $this->input->post('order_type'));
   
  $this->load->samplemodel_model->create('orders', $data);

        //I'm not so sure if it is in this function that I should place the unset for the session 'last_inserted_id'

  redirect('home', 'refresh');
 }
}
```

And in my model, I inserted another function which helps me saving the last id inserted. Here's it:

```html
public function get_last_inserted($id)
 {
    $this -> db -> select('customer_id');
    $this -> db -> from('customers');
    $this -> db -> where('customer_id', $id);
    $this -> db -> limit(1);
  
    $query = $this -> db -> get();
  
    if($query -> num_rows() == 1)
    {
      return $query->result();
    }
    else
    {
      return false;
    }
 }
```

PLEEEASE! HELP :'( I would really appreciate if you have any other ideas. THANK YOU SOOOOO MUCH!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you're redirecting, Each HTTP request is it's own process with it's own variables, and each request can't access the variables set in other requests.

Try passing the customer ID as a parameter to addOrders(), you can then use the codeigniter way of passing params around :

http://www.example.com/controller/method/paramter

Check the docs :

https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/controllers.html

under the segment : **Passing URI Segments to your Functions**

Other possible solution : Store the customerID in the session, or in a user object you instantiate when you create a new user, but that's more dependent of the use case.

Comment: I already tried using your first solution, it doesn't work for me. I mean, I think I just don't know how to use it properly (hehe). What I am trying right now is using session. I already got the ID but there's a little problem as I use the session. But anyways, thank you very much for your answer. I appreciate it a lot.

Comment: Well if you want to edit your question and explain what's the problem I(or someone else) might explain further

Comment: I've got this little problem in using session. The other session for getting the last id inserted overrides the session for log-in. (facepalm)

Comment: Update your question as I don't see you storing the customer id to any session:)

Comment: hello @Patrick, I already edited the question. I added the new lines that I had tried awhile ago. Thank you.